# Spring Boot Restfull api get : nesting excepion

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I want to use @RestController and  @RequestMapping make a restfull api service project, but when I use appDao.findAll() to get all apps, get nesting excepion, code like:

App.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "apps")
public class App {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;


    @NotNull
    private String name;

    public App() { }

    public App(String name, User user) {
        this.name = name;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    public User getUser(){
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){

        return "AppName: " + name;
    }


}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    // ------------------------
    // PRIVATE FIELDS
    // ------------------------

    // An autogenerated id (unique for each user in the db)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;


    // The user's email
    @NotNull
    private String email;

    // The user's name
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private Integer age;

    // ------------------------
    // PUBLIC METHODS
    // ------------------------

    public User() { }

    public User(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User(String email, String name, Integer age) {
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    // Getter and setter methods

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long value) {
        this.id = value;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String value) {
        this.email = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer value) {
        this.age = value;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_id")
    private Car car;
    public Car getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    public void setCar(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=App.class, mappedBy="user", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<App> apps;

    public Set<App> getApps() {
        return apps;
    }

    public void setApps(Set<App> apps) {
        this.apps= apps;
    }

    public void addApps(Set<App> apps) {
        this.apps.addAll(apps);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = String.format(
                "User[id=%d, name='%s']%n",
                id, name);
        if (apps != null) {
            for(App app : apps) {
                result += String.format(
                        "app[id=%d, name='%s']%n",
                        app.getId(), app.getName());
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
} // class User
```

AppDao.java

```
@Transactional
public interface AppDao extends JpaRepository<App, Long> {

    /**
     * This method will find an User instance in the database by its email.
     * Note that this method is not implemented and its working code will be
     * automagically generated from its signature by Spring Data JPA.
     */

}
```

AppController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/apps")
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    private AppDao appDao;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public List<App> getAll() {
        List<App> apps = appDao.findAll();
        return apps;
    }
}
```

Main Java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration 
public class MysqlDemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MysqlDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
    }

}
```

then visit :http://localhost:8080/apps/ get nested exception: why?

backtrace:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]

    2016-06-28 11:01:18.675 ERROR 90592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:109) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView.render(ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java:195) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1246) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1029) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:523) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:439) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:304) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:179) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]

    2016-06-28 11:01:18.678 ERROR 90592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:523) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:439) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:304) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:179) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:109) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView.render(ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java:195) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1246) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1029) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Comment: There's something you're not showing. Sharing a sample that reproduces the issue is always better that plenty of code in the description.

Comment: Show your application main class. Edit: and/or the whole stack trace.

Comment: thank you , I update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do you call your DAO code directly from Controller class? It is considered a bad practice - you should have Service class between them.

Secondly, the stacktrace you provided is about error while application tries to render error screen under path /error, is there any stacktrace before this?

According your problem - try to specify http method to your RequestMapping on method, i.e.:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

If this doesn't work there must be some error in your Spring configuration, do you correctly specify packages to scan for components? In Spring Boot when you are using @SpringBootApplication all packages to scan must be below class with this annotation.

***UPDATE***

Do not return entity with circular dependencies via REST webservice - create new DTO class, map entities fetched from database and return it in webservice.

More info here: http://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application

Of course if you want you may use another mapping library, my personal favourite is Orika (http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/intro.html)

Comment: I debugg that:

```java
public List<App> getAll() {
        List<App> apps = appDao.findAll();
        System.out.println("*************");
        System.out.println(apps.size());
        return apps;
    }
```

there is 5 records in database, but when I visit http://localhost:8080/apps/, I got many repeat nesting records, like 


    [{"id":317,"name":"BA","user":{"id":131,"email":"mailA@163.com","name":"User A","age":19,"car":null,"apps":[{"id":317,"name":"BA","user":{"id":131,"email":"mailA@163.com","name":"User A","age":19,"ca

Comment: See "UPDATE" section in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using wrong **Accept header**. If you are trying to request your service from web browser this request will have standard header values with **application/xhtml+xml** value and it causes the problem

You need to have correct header value with json for example **application/json**. Just use some other tools for requests like postman